# Helm Release stuck in Uninstalling state

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, helm3

I was trying to uninstall a helm release in my AKS cluster using `helm uninstall RELEASE_NAME` but seems like it failed. The failure happened because for some reason all of the nodes in my cluster went in a not ready state when I used `helm uninstall`.

Since then, I got all the nodes to get back up and running and the cluster is functioning as it should. Now, when I do try `helm list`, I don't get to see this release present anymore, but doing a `helm list -a` shows me that the state of the release is still in `uninstalling` state. I have tried quite a few things, but it has been stuck there now for the last 3-4 days.

A few things that I tried was to use `helm uninstall RELEASE_NAME`, `helm delete --purge RELEASE_NAME` but these commands throw an error because the release is already in `uninstalling` state. I tried modifying the helm secrets in the cluster for this specific release but that didn't help either. `Helm3` is being used so it is not like I can restart the tiller pod to maybe stabilize this.

Does `Helm3` use some kind of a finalizer mechanism which can be modified to rectify this or
is there no alternate way in which I can perhaps try to delete this release? I want to use the same release name for the specific API in the future too.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: `helm hist releasename` , `helm rollback releasename versionnumber-with-status-deployed`. you will be good to delete after rollback

Comment: @Adiii, I tried to do this as well, but now the status shows up as `pending rollback`. I guess because it is stuck in the uninstalling state, so once that is resolved only then some other operations will work on the same release.

Comment: did you tried to delete secret for the current stuck release? `k delete secrets sh.helm.release.v1.name.v4`

Comment: Ok, I tried modifying the secrets but have not tried deleting them altogether. Will deleting it work? Anyway, I'll surely give it a try!

Comment: yes, but make sure to delete the version that is being stuck

Comment: Ok, so @Adiii, sh.helm.release.v1.name.v1 shows the status as `uninstalling` while sh.helm.release.v1.name.v2 shows the status as `pending rollback`. Should I be deleting both the secrets or the one with the `uninstalling` status that is v1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248775/discussion-between-adiii-and-saurav-saha).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Based on the discussion, the following steps resolve the issue.

```
helm hist releasename
helm rollback releasename versionnumber-with-status-deployed
```

if this did not help, then delete secret for each version

```
helm hist releasename
kubectl get secrets
k delete secrets sh.helm.release.v1.name.VERSION-N
```

Comment: I found the `kubectl delete secrets` hack to be necessary after failing to uninstall a release of an old chart referring to now-gone CRDs.

Comment: FWIW, I had a release I physically couldn't rollback, since it was the 1st one. Deleting the secret worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank-you.  Similarly I had to delete all `helm.sh/release.v1` secrets (not just the latest), after which all was good.  To do that, I ran this powershell: `kubectl get secrets -n  $MyNamespace | ?{$_ -match '^(\S+)\s+helm\.sh.*$'} | %{$Matches[1]} | %{kubectl delete secrets $_ -n $MyNamespace}`

Answer (score 13):

You can remove the helm chart forcibly by using --no-hooks flag.

Example:

helm uninstall -n <name_space> <stuck_helm_name> --no-hooks

Comment: This worked for me, the other solutions didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add "--debug" to the helm uninstall command it might give you a good hint (in my case it was missing permissions to delete cluster-role)